# IF Statement check if Control has Tag Value

Tags: c#

im trying to loop through some controls, and then make a rectangle from the control's location, width and height and add it to a list.

C#

```
List<Rectangle> MaskBlocks = new List<Rectangle>();
foreach (StackPanel gr in FindVisualChildren<StackPanel>(Container))
  if (gr.Tag.ToString() == "Blur")
  {
      System.Windows.Point tmp = gr.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
      MaskBlocks.Add(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point((int)tmp.X,(int)tmp.Y), new System.Drawing.Size((int)gr.ActualWidth, (int)gr.ActualHeight)));
  }
```

When I run the code I get an error in the IF Statement saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in BlurEffectTest.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Can someone shed some light on this so I can fix it?

Comment: The IF statement would be false? Or that would cause an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error says that you gr.Tag is null so it fails. Check if null first

```
List<Rectangle> MaskBlocks = new List<Rectangle>();
foreach (StackPanel gr in FindVisualChildren<StackPanel>(Container))
if (gr.Tag!= null && gr.Tag.ToString() == "Blur")
{
    System.Windows.Point tmp = gr.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
    MaskBlocks.Add(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point((int)tmp.X,(int)tmp.Y), new System.Drawing.Size((int)gr.ActualWidth, (int)gr.ActualHeight)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may get the exception when `gr.Tag is null` and   `C#`  is not capable of handling `null.ToString()`. so better to check for null before accessing value from it.

```
if (!(gr.Tag is null) && gr.Tag.ToString() == "Blur")
 {
  //Here comes your code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient but here but this may help others:

```
if (!(gr.Tag is null) && gr.Tag.GetType() == typeof(string) && (gr.Tag as string) == "Blur")
{
}
```